# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. Posting data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using this API to post apartment data, the data is being registered but I am always receiving the Error message: 'Can't set headers after they are sent.'

How can I solve this implementation to avoid this cenário?
I complemented the code with all the stack to access this API.

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/apartment', (req, res) => {
  Apartment.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'apartment_id',
      'apartment_floor',
      'apartment_size',
      'apartment_block_id',
      'apartment_block_name',
      'apartment_parking_id',
    ],
  })
    .then((apartments) => {
      //      console.log(documents);
      res.sendStatus(200).send(apartments);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('erro: ', err));
});

app.get('/apartment/:apartment', (req, res) => {
  Apartment.findByPk(
    {
      attributes: [
        'apartment_id',
        'apartment_block_id',
        'apartment_floor',
        'apartment_size',
        'apartment_block_name',
        'apartment_parking_id',
      ],
      where: {
        apartment_id: req.params.apartment_id,
        apartment_block_id: req.params.apartment_block_id,
      },
    },
  )
    .then((documents) => {
      res.sendStatus(200).send(documents);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("erro - API GET '/document: ", err));
});
app.post('/apartment', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.sendStatus(400).send({
      message: 'Content can not be empty!',
    });
  } else {
    Apartment.create({
      apartment_id: req.body.apartment_id,
      apartment_block_id: req.body.apartment_block_id,
      apartment_block_name: req.body.apartment_block_name,
      apartment_floor: req.body.apartment_floor,
      apartment_size: req.body.apartment_size,
      apartment_parking_id: req.body.apartment_parking_id,
    });
  }
  return res
    .sendStatus(200)
    .send({ message: ' [CREATED REGISTER] API POST:  /apartment' });
});
app.listen(config.port, () =>
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${config.port}!`),
);
```

Comment: Show your `root` file ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `return` 
before res....
I.E.

```
return res.sendStatus(400).send({
      message: 'Content can not be empty!',
    });
```

Comment: I add return, but is still presenting the same error

Comment: try: return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'Content can not be empty!',
    })

Comment: @RudsonRodrigues - If adding this return doesn't stop the error, then the error is apparently coming from some other code besides just what you've shown here because adding the return will stop that particular error in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
res.sendStatus(200).send(apartments);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
res.status(200).send('OK').send(apartments)
```

Meaning that you are trying to send a response twice:

```
res
  .status(200) // Set status code of response
  .send('OK') // Send the response!
  .send(apartments) // Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

Try setting `status` and using `send`:

```
res
  .status(200) // Set status code of response
  .send(apartments) // Send the response
```

Also add `return` in all `res.status().send()` to avoid reaching multiple attempts per request.

Comment: Thanks @Rshomon, but I am facing the same issue after update the code.

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (..\parking_backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (..\parking_backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json
...